# What is the derivation of A not being a proper subset of B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The exact question is actually "Derivation A ⊄ B", and I am **assuming** that derivation in this case means to prove and give an example of when this is true? If it is then A is not a proper subset of B when A = B, or when A contains elements that are not in B.

If I am wrong, can someone explain to me what the term 'derivation“  means in that context of the question "Derivation of A ⊄ B"

It seems to be asking for the formal definition of proper subset with its negation, does anyone know what the formal definition of a proper subset is? I can't seem to find a formal definition on google.

Comment: You should provide some context, as right now I (for one) have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: Whatever the contxt, "proof" seems to match

Comment: I made an edit to it, does anyone happen to know what the formal definition of a proper subset is?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. We say that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ if $A \neq B$ and every $a \in A$ is also in $B$ (i.e. $a \in A \implies a \in B$). Sometimes people use the notation $A \subset B$ to mean $A \subseteq B$, so even if $A = B$, one might write $A \subset B$.